# How to replace gif on screen with another one in java?

Tags: java, swing, loading

I want to open the loading gif for 5 seconds and then switch to another gif, but I'm unable to switch

I've tried frame.dispose(), Panel.removeAll(), and a whole lot of other functions

```
        setSize(1366, 768);
        setLocation(0, 0);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\hmi-loading.gif");
        JLabel imagelabel = new JLabel(image);
        imagelabel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        imagelabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        p.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        p.add(imagelabel);
        getContentPane().add(p);
        p.removeAll();
        frame.removeAll();
        p.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        ImageIcon imagee = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\kAi.gif");
        JLabel imagelabel1 = new JLabel(image);
        imagelabel1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        imagelabel1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        p.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        p.add(imagelabel1);
        getContentPane().add(p);
```

That is one gif..
How do I add a timer so that this one gets replaced by another?

I expect the gif to be replaced by the other one.
The gif opens, and thats about it.

Comment: Use a `Swing Timer`. When the Timer fires you reset the `Icon` of the `JLabel` using the `setIcon(...)` method (don't create a new JLabel). Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more information.

Comment: @camickr Can I privately reach you somehow? There's a bunch of questions I have in mind...

Comment: This is not a chat forum. Post your questions in the forum. Then anybody who reads the question has an opportunity to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple example based on the [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) API.

```
public class ImageView extends JFrame {

    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel label;
    private Timer timer;

    public ImageView() {

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(640, 480);

        panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\hmi-loading.gif"));
        panel.add(label);

        timer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\kAi.gif"));
            }
        });

        timer.start();

        this.getContentPane().add(panel);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new ImageView());
    }
}
```

I didn't have enough time right now for testing it but this minimal snippet should work.

Comment: Just put your additional question into comments or the [StackOverflow Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/), thanks

Comment: @0x1C1B to make your code mcve consider using public resources : `URL url1 = new URL("https://findicons.com/files/icons/345/summer/128/cake.png");
        URL url2 = new URL("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/atyourservice/service-categories/128/Sweets-icon.png");
        label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(url1));`